# React native app, Fastlane can't create build on Bitrise. However on local machine we can create build

Tags: reactjs, gradle, native, bitrise

This is my lane

```
lane :alpha do 
    begin

    version_code = increment_version_code(
      gradle_file_path: "./app/build.gradle"
    )
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease --info")
    supply(
      track: "alpha",
      apk: "#{lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]}"
    )

    git_commit(
      path: "./app/build.gradle", 
      message: "Fastlane Android: Release new build #{version_code} [ci skip]"
    )

    on_success()
    rescue => exception
      on_error(exception)
    end 
  end
```

On local machine gradle works perfect and the build is created and supply finishes successfully. On Bitrise I have this error: 

 `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[13:58:23]: ▸ * What went wrong:
[13:58:23]: ▸ Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[13:58:23]: ▸ > Could not list contents of '/bitrise/src/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/.bin/sane'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.`

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11212 ?

Comment: Also you can remote access or SSH into the build VM to have an interactive debug environment https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/remote-access/